# rsync - include "only" source directories

Tags: rsync

Say I have the below top level folders

Drive1:

```
./Folder 1
./Folder 2
```

Drive2:

```
./Folder 1
./Folder 2
./Folder 3
./Folder 4
```

How can I sync only Folder 1 and 2 from Drive1 to Drive2, with the below conditions

- Full sync of `Folder 1` and `Folder 2` from Drive1 (including Deletes)
- Do not touch `Folder 3` and `Folder 4` on Drive2
- I do not want to specify the folders to ignore using `--exclude-from` option (as I want this to be a generic solution for any given drives)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rsync -a --delete "/src/path/Folder 1/" "/dst/path/Folder 1/"
rsync -a --delete "/src/path/Folder 2/" "/dst/path/Folder 2/"
```

Or, if you have the folder names in `$@`:

```
for name in "$@"; do
    rsync -a --delete "/src/path/$name/" "/dst/path/$name/"
done
```

You would get the folder names in `$@` by either

```
set -- "Folder 1" "Folder 2"
```

or by calling the script (which this would be) like

```
./script "Folder 1" "Folder 2"
```

You wouldn't, as far as I can see, be able to use `--include` to pick only the wanted directories because then you would have to explicitly also exclude the directories that you didn't want to transfer (which is what you wanted to avoid).